# Postgres data query using epoch timestamp as input from client?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am in need to select all rows from table `a` that have `updated_at` newer than a given (epoch) timestamp, '1549312452' for example.

I am using node.js. When the client sends up that timestamp, I have the server convert it to date:

```
var date = new Date(timestmapInt * 1000);
```

I then run the following query:

```
`select * from a where a.updated_at > ${date}`
```

When I hit the endpoint I get this error:

```
"syntax error at or near \"Feb\""
```

So, in general, how can I query records newer than a certain date if my incoming parameter is 1549312452 in Postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the raw epoch to to_timestamp:

```
select * from a where a.updated_at > to_timestamp(1549312452)
```

Comment: worked. I did not know about the to_timestamp() func. Thank you.